# href to id not working in Opencart

Tags: href, opencart

In information section, I have a menu with a href to id, but they are not working. I don´t know the reason since it´s very simpl. In the menu:

```
<a href="#terms-prices">PRECIOS</a>
```

In the section:

```
<h2 id="terms-prices">PRECIOS</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve finally fixed it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(function(){
          $('a[href^=#]').click(function(e){
            var id = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
            var pos = $('#' + id).offset().top - $('#nav').height() * 1.2;
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: pos });
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
    });
});
```